# Ajax request on same page not working got 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page

> http://localhost/test

which have the following code:

```
<?php

// Handle AJAX request (start)
if( isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['name']) ){
 echo $_POST['name'];
 exit;
}
// Handle AJAX request (end)
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

 <body >

  <form method='post' action>

   <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter your name' id='name'>
   <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'><br>
   <div id='response'></div>
  </form>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
     var name = $('#name').val();

     $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: {ajax: 1,name: name},
      success: function(response){
       $('#response').text('name : ' + response);
      }
     });
    });
  });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The code is taken from https://makitweb.com/how-to-handle-ajax-request-on-the-same-page-php/

I got the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>
> (Not Found) POST http://localhost/test 404 (Not Found)

Can anybody please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a good practice, you should move your PHP code to another file and call that file. You don't need to load the whole HTML in your Ajax response.

Comment: Just a rough guess since this is bad practice as already mentioned by @Nicolas: Do you need to rename your file to test.php and call http://localhost/test.php?